# Calling a python program from an external link and communicating with it

Tags: python, external

I have no idea if this has an official name, nor do I know a better way to really describe what I'm going for here so I'll list the two things I'd like to accomplish.

In a nutshell I have a task management program that emails people when they've been assigned a task. What I'd like is some way to generate a link (html or otherwise) that can be clicked that will either:

1. Launch the program with some command-line arguments, or
2. If the program is already open, communicate some commands to it, so that it could be, perhaps, set as the top window and then it could switch to the task.

I know this must be possible, but I have not yet gleaned the knowledge of how to communicate with programs outside of themselves. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you need a web app? You could create a RESTful api that does exactly this.

Comment: It's an entirely local/network-run program, though. It doesn't communicate with the web, but rather the network. So Ideally it'd just know that the user has the software installed and would work with it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I use tools like [itty](https://github.com/toastdriven/itty) and [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to implement this kind of functionality.

For example, using *itty* here's how you could launch a program with some command-line arguments:

```
from itty import *

@post('/someprogram/(?P<args>\w+)')
def launcher(request, args):
    'Launch a program with some command-line arguments'
    return subprocess.check_output('someprogram', shlex.split(args))

run_itty()
```

The front-end for this could be a simple web page with an html form to get command-line arguments and a submit button to make the POST request.

This approach works equally well over a local network or over the web.

Comment: Color me noobile, and I've gotten it to work on an extremely base level outside of a PyQT environment, but the @ portion when using itty is throwing syntax errors when I try to wrap it inside of a QThread. Any ideas how I might further deploy this or will I need to run it separately and try socket communications of some sort?